# Should I use a map when playing Mines of Madness in the D&D Next playtest?

Tags: published-adventures, maps, dnd-next-playtest

Should I use a map when playing Mines of Madness in the D&D Next playtest?

I can't tell if it's suppose to be run with the map or not. This will be our first time playing D&D.

Comment: Related: [Without a map or miniatures, how to best determine line-of-sight, etc?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/without-a-map-or-miniatures-how-to-best-determine-line-of-sight-etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Mines of Madness crawl does not require a map, but it will help a lot. Without a map, imagination is all there is to see the field and not all people will see a description the same. Maps keep everyone on the same pace and help things flow smoothly. I recommend using a map as first time role players, unless you want more of a challenge. Make sure you know the rules inside and out before attempting to play with out a map as distractions will lessen the enjoyment of the adventure due to a loss of detail (in know from personal experience).

Answer (score 2):

While D&D Next tells you a map is not necessary at all, most combat options involve distances, from the character having different speeds to the range of weapons to the area of spells.

I strongly advise you to use the gridded map: its use makes fictional positioning obvious and the rules support it.

Comment: Distances being present doesn't mean a grid is necessarily better. (D&D had distances from the beginning and worked fine without a grid for over three decades.) There are advantages and disadvantages to both; but often the most significant deciding factor is simply which way the group is used to.